# Rails 5.1 get data from database depending on the date (group_by involved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, group-by, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a rails app for my expenses. I have several models like user, spending, currency. I put relations between them, everything works. I can add a new expense that is shown on a index (all the expenses from all users) and I decided to loop through the expenses on the user show page, where the current_user see his own expenses.
I also grouped the expenses by date (month and year) and I have a "Today" group, which shows all the expenses entered on the day. It looks like this in the controller :

```
def show

    @user_spendings = @current_user.spendings.all.order('date DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 
                          10)

 #Retrives all messages and divides into two groups todays messages and other messages
    @grouped_spendings = @user_spendings.group_by{ |t| t.date.to_date == DateTime.now.to_date }

    if @user_spendings.present?
      #Create month wise groups of messages      
      @month_wise_sorted_spendings  = @user_spendings.group_by{ |t| (Date::MONTHNAMES[t.date.month] + " " + t.date.year.to_s) }
    end  

end
```

This is my view :

```
<% if @grouped_spendings.present? && @grouped_spendings[true].present? %>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

  <h3>Today</h3>

<tbody>
  <% @grouped_spendings[true].each do |spending| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= spending.title %></td>
    <td><%= spending.description %></td>
    <td><%= '%.02f' % spending.amount %></td>
    <td><%= spending.currency.symb %></td>
    <td><%= spending.date.strftime('%d %B %Y') %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<% end %> 

</table>

<% end %>

<% if @month_wise_sorted_spendings.present? %>
<% @month_wise_sorted_spendings.each do |hash_elements|%>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

  <% date_in_link = "#{hash_elements.first}" %>
  <h3><%= link_to(date_in_link, detail_result_path) %></h3>

<tbody>
  <% hash_elements.last.each do |spending| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= spending.title %></td>
    <td><%= spending.description %></td>
    <td><%= '%.02f' % spending.amount %></td>
    <td><%= spending.currency.symb %></td>
    <td><%= spending.date.strftime('%d %B %Y') %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<% end %> 

</table>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to create a link on the month and year and open a page where all the informations are looped again but only for this specific month of the year.
I already achieved the linking with this :

```
<% date_in_link = "#{hash_elements.first}" %>
  <h3><%= link_to(date_in_link, detail_result_path) %></h3>
```

To avoid mixing the controllers etc... I decided to create new controller called `detail` and a `result.html.erb` page where I will loop the expenses about the specific month and year.
Which way should I take with this ? Is it a good option to do a new controller ? And how can I get the infos back according to the date on my new page ?
I thought about passing some `params` via the `link_to` but I'm not sure it's the best solution. Maybe there is something easier but I don't know or see it.
If anyone can help would be great !
Thanks alot

Comment: Ok I changed my mind. I will use the same controller so it's not going all around the place. I added a `do
    match :detail, :via => [:get]
   end`
on my resources :users in the routes to get `/users/2/detail` in the URL. I should consider a if statement to gatter the infos from one specific month. Still working on that, didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: I changed the link to that in the show `<% date_in_link = "#{hash_elements.first}" %>
  <h3><%= link_to(date_in_link, user_detail_path(@current_user, hash_elements.first)) %></h3>`. I have that in my URL now `/users/2/detail.January%202018`. Maybe I could use some params now in the detail view to loop the expenses through the specific date ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer but it's on a other post I did as I had an other problem before this one. So the link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366294/rails-5-1-group-by-year-and-month-and-show-both/48384644#48384644)
Feel free to ask question if any